Comparative Analysis: IC Buck Converters vs. General Buck Converter Schematics
I am working on correlating the schematic of an IC-based buck converter with the design principles and structure of a general buck converter circuit.

Based on the schematic I created, all critical elements of the IC-based buck converter (e.g., PWM and feedback network) are present, but there is no external diode. Does this indicate that a diode is integrated into the IC itself, or has it been eliminated altogether? If it is integrated, what is the rationale behind this design choice? Why not use an external diode, as with other components like the inductor and capacitors?

Synchronous buck controller?

@winny I did not know what is an "Synchronous buck controller" and I noticed "A Synchronous Buck Controller is a type of buck converter controller that uses two active switches—typically MOSFETs—instead of a diode in the power stage. This design improves efficiency by reducing power losses, particularly at higher load currents.". So do you mean the IC-based convertor is a Synchronous buck controller?

"the IC-based convertor is a Synchronous buck controller?" Which IC?

You tell me. You know the part name for it. We don't.

@winny Yes, I read the datasheet sheet and it is mentioned there are 4 Synchronous buck controller, thanks for the very important keyword, it was very helpful.

When the switch transistor in the converter chip turns off, the voltage at the left end of the inductor wants to go negative. The diode shorts this to GND, which sends the energy in the inductor to the load. Sometimes manufacturers embed another MOSFET inside the chip that is performing the same role as the external Schottky diode (This is what you mentioned as Synchronous Buck Controller).
You should check your IC's datasheet for reference designs. If there is no diode then your controller may be a Synchronous Buck Controller and handling this situation internally. If reference design shows diodes to use then you should consider adding diode(s) to your circuit.
